# Error in R: multi effects models

Tags: r, hierarchical-data

I'm having a few issue's I'd appreciate some help with.

```
 head(new.data)
  WSZ_Code Treatment_Code Year Month TTHM CL2_FREE      BrO3 Colour  PH  TURB seasons
1        2              3 1996     1 30.7     0.35 0.5000750   0.75 7.4 0.055  winter
2        6              1 1996     2 24.8     0.25 0.5001375   0.75 6.9 0.200  winter
3        7              4 1996     2 60.4     0.05 0.5001375   0.75 7.1 0.055  winter
4        7              4 1996     2 58.1     0.15 0.5001570   0.75 7.5 0.055  winter
5        7              4 1996     3 62.2     0.20 0.5003881   2.00 7.6 0.055  spring
6        5              2 1996     3 40.3     0.15 0.5003500   2.00 7.7 0.055  spring

        library(nlme)
    > mod3 <- lme(TTHM ~ CL2_FREE, random= ~ 1| Treatment_Code/WSZ_Code, data=new.data, method ="ML")
    > mod3
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
      Data: new.data 
      Log-likelihood: -1401.529
      Fixed: TTHM ~ CL2_FREE 
    (Intercept)    CL2_FREE 
       54.45240   -40.15033 

    Random effects:
     Formula: ~1 | Treatment_Code
            (Intercept)
    StdDev: 0.004156934

     Formula: ~1 | WSZ_Code %in% Treatment_Code
            (Intercept) Residual
    StdDev:    10.90637 13.52372

    Number of Observations: 345
    Number of Groups: 
                  Treatment_Code WSZ_Code %in% Treatment_Code 
                               4                            8 
    > plot(augPred(mod3))
    Error in plot(augPred(mod3)) : 
      error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': Error in sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain), ...) : 
      invalid type of argument[1]: 'symbol'
```

I'm not sure why I get this error. The ranef plot seems OK

```
plot(ranef(mod3))
```

But that only gives the value of the random intercepts, no TTHM predictions. 
I'm looking for a way to plot the predictions like in a typical augPred which would show all the random effects for each zone. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Omnia, welcome to SO! Could you please provide a reproducible example, including a (potentially limited) dataset, all the libraries that you use, and the specific command that generates this error message? Otherwise we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I'll try below. I'm very amateur at R so bare with me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a groupedData object to use augPred. I hope this helps.

Best wishes @CSJCampbell

```
con <- textConnection("
WSZ_Code Treatment_Code Year Month TTHM CL2_FREE      BrO3 Colour  PH  TURB seasons
        2              3 1996     1 30.7     0.35 0.5000750   0.75 7.4 0.055  winter
        6              1 1996     2 24.8     0.25 0.5001375   0.75 6.9 0.200  winter
        7              4 1996     2 60.4     0.05 0.5001375   0.75 7.1 0.055  winter
        7              4 1996     2 58.1     0.15 0.5001570   0.75 7.5 0.055  winter
        7              4 1996     3 62.2     0.20 0.5003881   2.00 7.6 0.055  spring
        5              2 1996     3 40.3     0.15 0.5003500   2.00 7.7 0.055  spring
")
new.data <- read.table(con, header = TRUE)

library(nlme)

new.data.grp <- groupedData(TTHM ~ CL2_FREE | Treatment_Code/WSZ_Code, data = new.data)
mod3 <- lme(TTHM ~ CL2_FREE, random= ~ 1| Treatment_Code/WSZ_Code, data=new.data.grp, method ="ML")
mod3
ap3 <- augPred(mod3)
plot(ap3)
```

Comment: Thank you @CSJCampbell! I actually done it a similar way. 
I grouped Treatment_Code & WSZ_Code<br/>
    <pre><code>zone.treat <- data.frame(WSZ_Code=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), Treatment_Code=c("2", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1", "4", "1"), treatzone =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
new.data2 <- merge(new.data, zone.treat, by=c("WSZ_Code", "Treatment_Code"))<br/>
Then grouped to create spatial/temporal model

    mod14.new <- groupedData(TTHM ~ PH + CL2_FREE + treatzone| Year/seasons, data=as.data.frame(new.data2), FUN=mean, labels = list(x="Year/seasons", y= "TTHM"))     fml2 <- lme(mod14.new)

Comment: plot(mod14.new) gives BLUPs, but very strange ones, maybe issue with convergence. This works better:  
mod15.new <- groupedData(TTHM ~ CL2_FREE + 1| Year/seasons, data=as.data.frame(new.data2), FUN=mean, labels = list(x="Year/seasons", y= "TTHM"))
     but loses effect of zones, which ideally would have random effects.

Answer (score 0):

I realize most are probably using `ggplot2` and `lme4` at this point, but I'm a bit crufty.

Here are a couple of things that I've found working with lists of response variables that are fit using `lme()`.

So, I've been working with a number of response variables that I want to fit to a particular set of inputs. In short my code looks something like

```
mymodels = list()
for(resp in my_response_vars){
    f = as.formula(paste(resp,paste(my_input_vars,collapse='+'),sep='~'))
    mymodels[[resp]] = lme(fixed=f,random=~wave|group,method="ML",
        data=mydata, na.action=na.exclude)
}
```

I've been successful in treating the entries in the resulting list as normal `lme()` objects. The problem comes when I want to plot predictions via `augPred()`. Specifically I get the following error,

```
Error in tapply(object[[nm]], groups, FUN[["numeric"]], ...) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

So, after much searching, I decided to have a look under the hood of `augPred()` via `debug()`. Here are some of the insights I came to... I'm not sure that these qualify as bugs or if they would require a patch, but I hope they can help others with similar problems.

1. When calling `augPred()` the function looks for the name of the data that was used in the original `lme()` call, then inherits this object from the `parent.frame()` via a call to `eval()`. I'm not sure if this defaults to the object frame or the global, but, when I change this to `data = object$data` in the debug, things work. So, ostensibly, if you have used a subset of these data in your model, it will call on the full set of data.
2. The above causes issues if one response has missing values and you are interested in one that does not. Since it includes everything in the data.frame as part of an eventual call to `gsummary()` the missing values in the non-response variable will throw a wrench into things.
3. So, missing values mess things up. I have defaulted to making a temporary data.frame with the columns of interest, then running `complete.cases()` on this prior to fitting the `lme()` model.

   ```
   mymods = list()
   for(resp in my_response_vars){
     f = as.formula(paste(resp,paste(my_input_vars,collapse='+'),sep='~'))
     v2keep = all.vars(f) # grab terms
     smdat = mydata[,c(v2keep,'group')] # include group
     smdat=smdat[complete.cases(smdat),] # scrub missing
     tmpmod = lme(fixed=f, random=~wave|group, 
                   method='ML', data=smdat)
     mymods[[resp]] = tmpmod
     # include augPred() call here
   }
   ```
4. If you are not including a primary argument in your call to `augPred()` it will require that your `data.frame` is a `groupedData()` object.

So, if you are running into the `arguments must have the same length` error, try: subsetting your data first under a different name, make sure to clear out missing rows explicitly prior to fitting your model.